# How to migrate a Postgresql column with a new enum type?

Tags: postgresql, migration, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize to write my schema and have a `File` model with a `file_type` column defined as:

```
file_type: {
  type: Sequelize.ENUM(
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png',
    'image/gif',
    'audio/mpeg3',
    'audio/wav',
    'application/pdf',
    'application/msword',
    'application/x-compressed',
  ),
  allowNull: false,
},
```

I need to alter this enum to use a new *mimeTypesEnum* which also includes some of the currently used values:

```
queryInterface.changeColumn('files', 'file_type', {
  type: mimeTypesEnum,
  allowNull: false,
}),
```

Of course, this does not work, as it attempts to redefine the *enum_files_file_type*.

It seems I have a couple options:

1. Iterate through all new types in *mimeTypesEnum* and run an `ADD VALUE` query on the *enum_files_file_type* type.
2. Drop the `file_type` column along with the *enum_files_file_type* type, and the above *changeColumn* function will work.

Option **1** I feel will get unnecessarily complicated, having to iterate over old and new types, figuring which already exist, which to add BEFORE or AFTER, etc... and it is als not un-doable so I can't write a *down* function.

Option **2** I will lose all the data currently in the `file_type` column, and since it is `allowNull: false` I will also have to provide a `defaultValue` which I do not want this column to have.

**Is there a simple, clean way I can migrate this column while persisting the current data?**